# App crashing after iAd implementation

Tags: ios, crash, iad

I'm all new to programming apps for iOS. But I have read multiple tutorials, and still I cant make it work. And yes I have searched a lot on StackOverFlow too ;-)

**How do I implement iAd to a single view in an App that uses storyboard?**

As far as I have read, i need to import the iAd/iAd.h, and many other things. I have followed many tutorials (new and old), but somehow I cant make it work. I would love to share my code with you, but I dont know which of it, when I have tested multiple tutorials?

When I open the app it crashes. Does any of you have a tutorial that you know works? Or some advice and code examples (I would really love that..) Im kind of stuck at the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect a property to iAd and in viewDidLoad set the delegate...

```
 self.iad.delegate = self;
```

Implement the following methods...

```
  -(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
     banner.hidden = NO;
}
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
     banner.hidden = YES;
}
```

Remember to get the delegate of IAd in your .m file...

```
  @interface yourViewController ()<ADBannerViewDelegate>
```

You still have to import IAd...

```
  #import <iAd/iAd.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to import the iAd framework and link the binary with your project. You then want to drag a banner view onto your storyboard and hook it up as an outlet. Then set the delegate property of the banner to be the view controller,  and implement the two delegate methods, as defined in the apple documentation.